# Jstl String to Number parse issue

Tags: jstl

I am parsing string to number for comparison with zero(0). But getting weird result.

```
<fmt:parseNumber type ="number" var="parsedNumber" value="${noInStringFormate}"/>

<c:if test="${parsedNumber gt 0}">
    Perform some action
</c:if>
```

Ex. for String "10.20" its parsed to Number 10.20.
But for String "0.23" its parsed to Number 0(zero) instead of 0.23

Even I tried by setting integerOnly="false" though its false by default. But its didn't work.

any idea on this?

Thanks for help.